# How to pass data-id variable from modal to php page

Tags: javascript, php, href, bootstrap-modal

I have the following DELETE button that I am passing $userid through the data-id

```
<a href='#myModal' class='trash' data-id='".$userid."' role='button'data-toggle='modal'>
    Delete</a>
```

I have the following modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>You are about to delete <b><i class="title"></i></b> record, this procedure is irreversible.</p>
                <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"  id="modalDelete">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following JS which gets the value of the DELETE button

```
$('.trash').click(function(){
   var id=$(this).data('id');   
   $('#modalDelete').attr('href','delete_user.php?id=' + id);
});
```

I am trying to set the value of the "href" in the modal so that it can be passed to a php page called delete_user.php which deletes the user from the database. Anyone see where I am going wrong? I cannot get the href to go to the delete_user.php

Comment: If `ajax`, send `id` in `data`

Comment: Try to log the value of id in console. What you get ?

Comment: Your JS code works just fine, I think you've have problem in setting the data-id value using PHP. https://jsfiddle.net/5o544wfL/

Comment: @Alok yeah it wont let me set the href value to be delete_user.php...Getting the id to the modal seems fine, but when i click the delete button i am trying to set the href location to be delete_user.php?id=id and then get the value of this in that page, but it aint even redirecting to that page

Answer (score 1):

you have mistake here `data-id='".$userid."'` should be `data-id='<?php echo $userid;>'`

```
<a href='#myModal' class='trash' data-id='<?php echo $userid;>' role='button'data-toggle='modal'>
Delete</a>
```

and for better approach, get rid of `click` function, use [modal event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) and let bootstrap handle the rest

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    alert(id);
    $('#modalDelete').attr('href', 'delete_user.php?id=' + id);
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfnLtsn1/)

Comment: still not navigating to delete_user.php, thanks for the tips !

Comment: so where it does navigate?

Comment: its not doing anything when i click the delete button in the modal?

Comment: updated this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cfnLtsn1/1/, to check the delete href set or not dynamically and if not, then first thing you need to check is `id="modalDelete"` is unique or not through out the document

Comment: still no change, maybe im doing something really stupid here, im not getting any alert popping up like the jsfiddle, this is the link appearing when i press the delete button; http://localhost/NewPhpProject/admin.php#

Comment: if using modal event, switch back to click function and then check and if modal event change `href='#myModal'` to `modal-target="#myModal"` also change the modal event to `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) { //rest of the code });`