# PHP $_GET variable causing issue

Tags: php, get

I have a link in a table that has an id that is passed to another page

**admin_shifts.php**

```
<a href=admin_shifts_view.php?id=1>view</a>
```

I get this value in the second page and use it to create a table from sql data

**admin_shifts_view.php**

```
$shifts_id = $_GET['id']
```

I click a button to delete that shift which takes me to ...

```
<a href=delete_from_shift.php?userid=" . $user_id ."&shiftid=" .$shift_id.">Remove</a>
```

**delete_from_shift.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['userid'])){

$user_id = $_GET['userid'];
$shifts_id = $_GET['shiftid'];

$delete_sql = "DELETE FROM user_shifts WHERE user_id=" . $user_id . " AND shifts_id=" .$shifts_id;
$delete_result = $database->query($delete_sql);

$deleted = "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Employee successfully removed</div>";

}else{

$deleted = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Problem removing employee at this time</div>";

}

$_SESSION['delete_user'] = $deleted; 
header("location:admin_shifts_view.php");
```

So when I redirect to admin_shifts_view.php I get an Undefined Index error. Any suggestions?

Comment: impossible to answer; not enough code. Otherwise, use `isset()` or `!empty()` in a conditional. If this is db related, could be an issue there too.

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: have a load of code just wanted to keep it simple. would it be a good idea to store the variable for shifts_id in sessions and dnt unset it?

Comment: anything to do with your previous last question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/36550004/ as for your last comment; sure, why not.

Comment: No nothing to do with a modal, let me post more code ...

Comment: `$shifts_id` != `$shift_id` there's your problem as per your `"&shiftid=" .$shift_id."` and you need to check if all are set, not just the one. E

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry that was just a typing error its actually correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass the parameter on again in the `header()`

```
header("location:admin_shifts_view.php?id=$user_id");
```

Comment: should be named `id` instead of `userid` here (look at admin_shifts_view.php), and I think he wants the `$shifts_id` to be passed along

Comment: Woops you are absolutely right. Got a bit lost there for a sec, its gone midnight here

Comment: It always is when you know the answer